# Excel: What if a particular team had not entered a league-based tournament

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

Imagine a tournament where four teams entered as shown in the above image. (The Score in Table1 shows the score for both teams; for Team 2 the plus/minus sign is inverted.)

How can I perform the following analysis:

> What would the new final standing be had TeamC not entered the tournament? (All the matches of TeamC should be ignored/discarded.)

(Just in case, [the example file is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1pgytzd2am82th/tournament-exclude-team.xlsx?dl=0))

Comment: Yes Excel can do it, Excel can do a lot of stuff, for an exact answer though you would need an exact question to a specific problem, asking for a way to approach a subject can only result in opinion based answers

Comment: I feel like that edit clarifies the question enough to qualify - we need a way to tell the Team/TotalScore table on the left only to sum scores from Table2 if the Round number and Team name don't both appear in a row from Table1 along with TeamC. Or give the sheet some way to discount data in Table1 that appears in a row that contains the string "TeamC"...

Comment: Important to help me formulate an answer - what formulas are you using to move data from one table to the next? Is all the data in tables 1 and 2 manually entered, or does the data in Table2 auto-generate based on the data in Table1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive solution that uses an auto-refreshed Pivot Table to display the alternate final standing dynamically when a team is excluded via a dropdown list.

It removes the excluded team from the Pivot Table and `Table2` completely, with the tables auto-adjusting to remove any blanks.

For `Table1`, it dims the rows containing the excluded team with conditional formatting. The best that can be down with this table is to hide the rounds completely, leaving blank rows.

Here is your worksheet showing the added modifications:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

**Formulas:**

Note that all the following formulas use Excel 2007 structured references, but will work in all later versions of Excel as well.

Formula 1 - Entered in `F1:F14`:

```dart
=1+INT((ROW()-ROW(Table1[Round]))/2/COUNTIFS(Table1[Round],1,Table1[Team1],"<>"&$K$9,Table1[Team2],"<>"&$K$9))
```

Formula 2 - Array entered (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in `G3` and copy-pasted/filled-down in `G3:G14`:

```dart
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[[Team1]:[Team2]],SMALL(IFERROR(1/(1/N(IF(1,(ROW(Table1[Round])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Round]]))*(Table2[[#This Row],[Round]]=Table1[Round])*($K$9<>Table1[Team1])*($K$9<>Table1[Team2])))),FALSE),1+MOD(INT((ROW()-ROW(Table1[Round]))/COUNTIFS(Table1[Round],1,Table1[Team1],"<>"&$K$9,Table1[Team2],"<>"&$K$9)),COUNTIFS(Table1[Round],1,Table1[Team1],"<>"&$K$9,Table1[Team2],"<>"&$K$9))),1+MOD(ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[Round]])-1,2)),"")
```

The prettified Formula 2 is as follows:

```dart
=
IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    Table1[[Team1]:[Team2]],
    SMALL(
      IFERROR(1/(1/N(IF(1,
         (ROW(Table1[Round])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Round]]))
        *(Table2[[#This Row],[Round]]=Table1[Round])
        *($K$9<>Table1[Team1])
        *($K$9<>Table1[Team2])
      ))),FALSE),
      1+MOD(
        INT((ROW()-ROW(Table1[Round]))/COUNTIFS(Table1[Round],1,Table1[Team1],"<>"&$K$9,Table1[Team2],"<>"&$K$9)),
        COUNTIFS(Table1[Round],1,Table1[Team1],"<>"&$K$9,Table1[Team2],"<>"&$K$9)
      )
    ),
    1+MOD(ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[Round]])-1,2)
  ),
  ""
)
```

Formula 3 - The formula in column `H` remains unchanged, repeated here for completeness:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Score]*(Table2[[#This Row],[Round]]=Table1[Round])*(Table2[[#This Row],[Team]]=Table1[Team1])-Table1[Score]*(Table2[[#This Row],[Round]]=Table1[Round])*(Table2[[#This Row],[Team]]=Table1[Team2]))
```

**Pivot Table:**

- The data source of the pivot table needs to be changed to `Table2`.
- The `Team` field needs to have blank values deselected.

[image: Pivot Table Setup Screenshot]

**Tables:**

`Table1` - Apply the following conditional formatting formula to the range `$A$3:$D$8`:

```dart
=OR($B3=$K$9,$C3=$K$9)
```

`Table1` - Apply the following number format to column `Score`:

```dart
0;-0;
```

`Exclude` - Set the data validation of `K9` to a dropdown list with the following source:

```dart
=$J$3:$J$6
```

**VBA:**

Add the following code to the Sheet Module of the worksheet:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address <> "$K$9" Then Exit Sub

  With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    Me.PivotTables(1).RefreshTable
    .EnableEvents = True
  End With

End Sub
```

This code simply refreshes the Pivot Table whenever the value in the excluded team changes. It is not strictly required for the solution to work, but then you would have to do a manually refresh after changing the team (by right-clicking the Pivot Table and selecting "Refresh", for example).

Answer (score -1):

With your current layout, you can show the adjusted scores in a regular third table (rather than the pivot table you currently have) like this:

I duplicated your sheet with a regular table instead of the pivot table, and added a named cell called "ExcludedTeam" so I could add a criteria to a `SUMIFS` function to go in the last table.

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Score],Table1[Team1],[@Team],Table1[Team2],"<>"&ExcludedTeam)-SUMIFS(Table1[Score],Table1[Team2],[@Team],Table1[Team1],"<>"&ExcludedTeam)
```

In normal english, this says "add the sum of the Scores from Table1 (where Team1 matches this Team AND Team2 doesn't match the Excluded Team) to the *inverse* of the sum of the Scores from Table1 (where Team2 matches this Team AND Team1 doesn't match the Excluded Team.)"

Of course, you could always hard-code the name of the excluded team into the formula, but that doesn't scale at all...

[image]

If you wanted TeamC's score to read as 0, you'd have to specifythat both Team1 and Team2 <> ExcludedTeam *in both halves of the formula*.

---

Edit: More functionality was needed as per comments, I describe how to get there below.

To remove any mention of the excluded team from all tables, you'd have to set the tables one above the other, so that hiding columns in Table1 won't hide any columns in Table2 and vice versa, or alternatively put them on separate sheets.

Once you've done that, make a macro that fires when you change the option selected in `ExcludedTeam` which sets the `.EntireRow.Hidden` property of any cell in either table whose `.Value = ExcludedTeam.Value` to `true`. All that's left is to change the specs of your pivot table to filter out that team, and you've got it.

Comment: In case you don't know how to name a cell, the spot in the top left corner of the attached image shows the name of the cell. Currently K3 is selected. Simply click on the cell you want to name (B10 in the image) then click in this space and type what you want the cell name to be. Heads up though - re-naming it or removing the name can be a pain.

Comment: Thank you. (1) I could not make your solution work. (2) To remove or rename a cell hit `CTRL`+`F3`, and `Name Manager` pops up. (3) Nonetheless I am looking for a solution in which when a team(s) is (are) excluded, they are not shown in the Standings.

Comment: "they are not shown in the standings" - what do you mean by this? You just want their total score to read as 0, or you want to be able to remove any mention of them from all tables?

Comment: "I could not make your solution work" - what about it isn't working? Is it not showing up as I displayed in the image, or are you just saying that the data in the image is not the result you're looking for?

Comment: Correct: (1) I want to be able to remove the mention of them in the final standings table. (2) When I apply your formula, I get different figures than shown in the image.

Comment: (1) ok, that'll be considerably more coding, I'll have a look and revise my answer. (2) There must be something different then. Are your two tables named "Table1" and "Table2" as indicated by the merged cells above? have you named the cell B10 "ExcludedTeam"? Have you copied the formula directly, or is there a chance you missed something copying it manually?

Comment: If you hide rows to get rid of mentions of TeamC, you'll need to reorganise: row 4 contains TeamC in Table1, but not in Table2, for example. To my knowledge you can only hide *sheet* rows, not *table* rows (the latter works by doing the former).

So you'd need to keep the tables on separate sheets, unless you know you'll never need more than that many rows per table...

Comment: Oh, and I just downloaded your version. You're using a pivot table. That's why you can't put the formula where I did...